# How to disable inline edit on a particular custom object list view?

Tags: list-view

How to disable inline edit on a particular custom object list view ?

Comment: you need to create custom VF for that

Comment: Well, it is not possible object wise. You will have to disable it for all Setup -> Customize -> User Interface -> Enable Inline Editing

Answer (score 1):

May not be the best solution but:

According to this document these are the following reason you cannot inline edit in a list view:

> Review the following Organization-specific
>   settings:
>
> If your
>   organization uses Record Types, you must include a Record Type Filter
>   for a single record type in the List View criteria. Inline editing
>   only works on lists that are filtered on a single
>   record type.
>
> **For
>   example:** "Record Type EQUALS Business Account", or "Record
>   Type EQUALS <blank>" for records
>   that don't have a record type.
>
> Inline
>   Editing from a list will not work if there are any "OR" filters in
>   conjunction with a record type filter (All list filters must be joined
>   by an "AND" logic).
>
> Also Record Type cannot be edited for Case
>   Object even if you have your list view filtered only on Single Record
>   type.
>
> ​
>   
>   **Good to
>   know:** Just having one Record Type in displayed records will not
>   enable Inline Editing. You must identify a single record type in the
>   List View criteria. If you don't have permission to edit the list
>   criteria, contact your System Administrator.
>
> If you are
>   attempting to inline edit tasks or events, you must include a filter
>   in the list criteria that restricts the list to displaying either tasks or events, not both. Include a
>   filter of "Task EQUALS True" to edit tasks, or
>   "Task EQUALS False" to edit events. If
>   you do not have permission to edit the list criteria, contact your
>   System Administrator.
>
> If your
>   organization uses Person Accounts (also known as B2C in some
>   organizations), you must include a filter in Account list views of
>   "Person Account EQUALS True" in order to edit Person Accounts. Likewise, use a
>   filter of "Person Account EQUALS False" in order to edit non-Person Accounts. Note that
>   Person Accounts are not
>   inline editable from Contact list views.
>
> Full Name fields on Person Accounts,
>   Contacts, and Leads are not inline editable, however, their component
>   fields are, such as First Name and Last
>   Name.
>
> Dependent
>   Picklist fields cannot be modified through the use of the inline
>   modification on list views.
>
> Filter Logic - You must clear out the filter
>   logic in order to use Inline Editing. They cannot be used
>   simultaneously.
>
> If a field is a part of look up filter criteria you will
>   not be able to inline edit the
>   field.
>
> A field must also be present on at least one page
>   layout in order to inline
>   edit.
>
> Inline editing is not available when the viewer
>   (User) has Accessibility Mode
>   enabled.
>
> The ability to inline edit multiple records
>   at once is also available, but you must have the "Mass Edit from
>   Lists" permission turned on for your user profile. Your System
>   Administrator can verify that your profile has this permission
>   enabled.
>
> ​
>   
>   **Note:** Product list views, you cannot edit multiple
>   records at once. Products can only be inline edited one at a time. If
>   you are unable to find the said permission on the profile, check if
>   "Enhanced Lists" are enabled via setup. (**Setup**
>   | **Customize** | **User Interface** | **Enable
>   Enhanced Lists**)

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003911

So with that I edited a list view as such to simply enable the filter logic.

[image]

**Notice the filter logic for 1 (No AND in the criteria)** without the AND it blocks inline editing

While this could be defeated if the user can edit the list view or creates their

If you have multiple criteria, simply repeat the criteria and use an OR

[image]

The only other option would be a custom VF page